# How to display correctly statuses with Twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter4j

I'm trying to dysplay the twitter statuses of a public person using Twitter4j. I dit it, but it's a very basic view with an Adapter.

[image]

I want to display it like on the website, with image ecc..

[image]

It's this possible?
That's what i've done so far:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)
    {
        statusListTextOnly = new ArrayList<String>();
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey("***************")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret(
                        "***************")
                .setOAuthAccessToken(
                        "***************-***************")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(
                        "***************");
        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        twitter = tf.getInstance();
        try {

            Long user;
            user = (long) ***************;
            statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(user);
            Log.i("Status Count", statuses.size() + " Feeds");
            for (twitter4j.Status status3 : statuses) {
                statusListTextOnly.add(status3.getText());
            }

        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
        }           
        return null;
    }//end background
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {   
        i.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, statusListTextOnly));
            //stuff
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the status object you can retrieve the required images.

```
User user = status.getUser();
user.getBiggerProfileImageURL();
user.getBiggerProfileImageURLHttps();
user.getOriginalProfileImageURL();
user.getProfileBackgroundImageURL();
```

You can explore User and Status objects and retrieve the information you need.
Also check this url - https://dev.twitter.com/web/overview/widgets-webpage-properties for how to use Twitter widgets to display Tweets.

Hope this helps.